Почему у меня не печатается pdf документ?
Пишу код, который должен создавать pdf документ. Сначала я сделал всё на локальной машине, а потом перенес код на сервер, а точнее на систему 1с битрикс.
На сервере он перестал работать, как надо (печатать документ), сейчас выдает белый лист.
function getKP() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/url/url.php",
                success: function (response) {
                    resolve(response);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.error("Ошибка при отправке запроса на бэкенд:", error);
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    async function calculate() {
        try {
            const forPerson = $("#for_person").val().trim();

            if (!forPerson) {
                alert("Пожалуйста, введите имя получения.");
                return;
            }

            let kp = await getKP();
            console.log(kp);

            const kpContainer = document.getElementById("kp-container");
            kpContainer.innerHTML = kp;

            // Настройки для генерации PDF
            const opt = {
                margin: 1,
                filename: `Коммерческое Предложение для ${forPerson} №.pdf`,
                html2canvas: {scale: 2, logging: true, dpi: 288, letterRendering: true, useCORS: true},
                jsPDF: {unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait'}
            };

            // Генерируем PDF из элемента
            html2pdf().from(kpContainer).set(opt).save();

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

Библиотеки поставлены:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

Вот что выводится при коде console.log(kp):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/KP.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>

<div class="content-block content">
    <div class="content-block2">
        <div class="flex justify-center header2 ">
 <img alt="Лого фирмы" src="/kalkulyator/assets/images/Logo.png" class="logo">
            <div class="info-block flex">
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                    <b>Текст</b>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Текст
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                    текст
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                    текст
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                    <b>Сайт:</b> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <div class="green">
            </div>
            <div class="gray">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kp-info flex justify-between margin-top-1 small-text">
 <i class="KP-counter"><b>КП003</b></i> 
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-between small-text">
 <i class="date"><b>От:</b></i> <i class="ferrum"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-top-1 flex justify-end small-text">
            <div>
                <i><b>Кому:</b></i>
            </div>
            <div class="client margin-left-1 ">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-center margin-top-1">
            <b>текст</b>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-top-1">
            текст
        </div>
        <table class="margin-top-1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                № п.п
            </th>
            <th>
                Наименование
            </th>
            <th>
                Описание
            </th>
            <th>
                Количество, шт
            </th>
            <th>
                Цена за единицу, руб.
            </th>
            <th>
                Сумма, руб.
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-content">
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="container margin-top-2">
            
            текст
        </div>
        <div class="line margin-top-2">
            <div class="green">
            </div>
            <div class="gray">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex footer margin-top-1 justify-between">
            <div class="KP-counter">
                КП003
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-end">
                <div>
                    Кому:
                </div>
                <div class="client margin-left-1 ">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="margin-left-015">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                текст
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Повторяя тоже самое, абсолютно тоже самое на локальной машине у меня печатается нужный документ.
Если же я решаю для теста добавить содержимое kp к странице, то тоже нормально добавляется снизу. Единственная проблема с печатью
UPDATE 27.08
В ходе эксперементов и кучи нажатий на кнопочку мне 1 раз удалось получить хоть что-то похожее на нужный мне документ. Код я никак не менял и как понимаю это просто удача.
У меня ощущения, что как-то блокирует печать 1с битрикс.

Попробуйте библиотеки скачать на свой сервер и вызывать их со своего сервера, а не с cdnjs.cloudflare.com.

@ВикторКарев это, к сожалению, не помогло мне.

Так у тебя даже вызова print в коде нет...

@Qwertiy я не использую принт. Я использую html2pdf().from(kpContainer).set(opt).save();. Как писал выше. На локальной машине всё работает. В то время, как на сервере - нет
